# Problem while saving data wit ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working on the comment part of my news portal project. I have the following code in the controller to save the comment:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $rules = $this->comments->getRules();
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name' => 'bail|required|string',
      'email' => 'bail|required|string',
      'comment' => 'required|string',
      'post_id' => 'required|numeric'
  ]);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
      return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()], 422);
  }

  $data = $request->all();
  $data['name'] = $request->name;
  $data['email'] = $request->email;
  $data['comment'] = $request->comment;
  $data['post_id'] = $request->post_id;
  $this->comments->fill($data);
  $status = $this->comments->save();

  if($status){
      return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>'You comment has been posted successfully. You should be able to see your comment once it is approved!']);
  } else {
      return response()->json(['status'=>false,'data'=>null]);
  }
}
```

And, I have following code in html:

```
<p id="comment-message"></p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label> <span>Comment *</span>
            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" required="" id="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label> <span>Name *</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required="" aria-required="true"> </label>
        <label> <span>Email Address *</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" required="" aria-required="true"> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="comment-submit">Post a Comment</button>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ @$data->id }}" id="post_id">
```

And in the ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#comment-submit').on('click', function(){
        let name = $('#name').val();
        let email = $('#email').val();
        let comment = $('#comment').val();
        let post_id = $('#post_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/comments",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", "_method": 'POST',name:name,email:email,comment:comment, post_id: post_id},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#comment').val('');
                //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response.status;
            },
            error: function(response){ console.log(response);
              $('#name').val('');
              $('#email').val('');
              $('#comment').val('');
              //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Now, when I try to populate comment without ajax the comments table is being populated but it is not populating with ajax. It is also not throwing any error. Am I missing anything in my ajax part?

Comment: What is the ajax response you get ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz The comment table is not populating to get the response.

Comment: Are you getting some response or not ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Not getting any response. And not getting error as well.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz There is no error on the console as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210090/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-eliesha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually because I did not set method key in the ajax.

Changing my ajax code to this worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#comment-submit').on('click', function(){
        let name = $('#name').val();
        let email = $('#email').val();
        let comment = $('#comment').val();
        let post_id = $('#post_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url:"/comments",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", "_method": 'POST',name:name,email:email,comment:comment, post_id: post_id},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#comment').val('');
                //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response.status;
            },
            error: function(response){ console.log(response);
              $('#name').val('');
              $('#email').val('');
              $('#comment').val('');
              //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    })
})
</script>
```

But still I wonder why it was not working when I have the method key defined in the `data:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the request and put the route in Web Route, you still need the CSRF Token to be passed in your Ajax Request, this is different when you put your route in Api Route. So what you need to do is 
1. Add token in your HTML header

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="_token" content="{{csrf_token()}}" />
</head>
```

And last, assign your token value to the header of your AJAX Request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```

Comment: From your code i read it as POST
`data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", "_method": 'POST',name:name,email:email,comment:comment, post_id: post_id}`

Comment: Can you give me your route?

Comment: You actually want to save a comment, you need a POST Method to do that

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying `method` in your ajax call. By default it is considered as `GET` request:

As per [Jquery ajax Documentatio](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)n:

> method (default: 'GET')
>
> Type: String The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST",
>   "GET", "PUT").

To resolve this add method: "POST" in your `ajax` call

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"/comments",
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "POST", // add this
        data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", "_method": 'POST',name:name,email:email,comment:comment, post_id: post_id},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#comment').val('');
            //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response.status;
        },
        error: function(response){ console.log(response);
          $('#name').val('');
          $('#email').val('');
          $('#comment').val('');
          //document.getElementById("comment-message").innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
```